# can't update concrete5 add ons with this error: Unable to locate this add-on on concrete5.org"

Tags: concrete5

I can't update all the add ons that I have installed, everytime I click that "update plugins" button, I got this error message: "Unable to locate this add-on on concrete5.org" on every plugins that i want to update

At first, I developed the website on my localhost. I connect it to the marketplace from there, so the URL of the project is something like this: locahost/myConcrete5Web,... in the middle of the development, I moved it to a development server. I'm not so sure if the problem appear on this server or not, cause I don't test the update functionality in here. By the way, when googling for the solution of my problem, I found the similarity of the case on this thread (http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/chat/marketplace-is-broken-on-upgrade-to-5.5/) with the one I have right now. So, just FYI, I do update the concrete5 version on this development server. From 5.5 to 5.6

My client start found the problem on the staging server. He tried to update the plugins and got that error message that I mentioned earlier. He told me and I started to google out for the solution. I found several clue from these pages:

- http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/chat/marketplace-is-broke...
- http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/editors/cant-connect...
- http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/installation/how-to-disco...

So, I tried to disconnect my website on the staging server by removing the value of MARKETPLACE_SITE_TOKEN & MARKETPLACE_SITE_URL_TOKEN on the database. Nothing changed. Next, I tried to delete the project listed on my concrete5 marketplace account. Turns out the problem getting worse. My concrete5 installatation still says that it is connected to the marketplace. They still show the project URL of the one that I have deleted before.

Now, I have no project listed on my account, when I tried to reconnect to the marketplace, it's show that i have successfully connect my web to concrete5 marketplace with the same project URL that I have deleted before. yet there's still no project listed on my account. Now, regarding the paid add ons, I'm kinda confused right now, where does my paid add on license go with this condition?? Do I still have it?

Anybody know how to resolve this problem?
Please feel free to ask for more clarification, my english is bad and I don't think my message could be understood well enough

*Not really sure if this is the correct place to post question like this. I've posted this on concrete5's forum with no response at all. I think this is the kind of issue that should be complained to the concrete5 team. The fault seems to be on how their marketplace work. But unfortunately, AFAIK, they don't give such technical support/bug report for this. So, I hope stackoverflow could help me out.*

Comment: Not having had this experience, I might suggest contacting Concrete5 via email and direct them to this post: help@concretecms.com

Comment: Also, have you checked if the addons still exist in the marketplace? The most obvious read of the error message is that the add-ons can't be found (sometimes addons get buggy and get removed).

Comment: @jamesS: I've make sure the addons still there on the marketplace